# Install Angular NgSelect module

Tags: angular, typescript, select, angular-ngselect

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-ngselect-with-single-multiple-and-search-filter-tutorial/#Install_Configure_ng-select) to install **Ngselect** module in an Angular app and got this error while serving app. I googled and couldn't find what is wrong here.

> ERROR in Unexpected value 'NgSelectModule in D:/ku-site/ku-web/node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/lib/ng-select.module.d.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in D:/ku-site/ku-web/ku-web/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        NgSelectModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Edit**: I missed the line `import { APP_INITIALIZER, ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';` while simplifying the code for the question.

Comment: Is it resolved now after importing NgModule?

Comment: No.. Still it's throwing the same error.

Comment: Do you missed the line **import { AppComponent } from './app.component';**  as well?

Comment: What are the versions of angular and ng-select you are using?

Comment: `Angular: 9.1.3` and `"@ng-select/ng-select": "^8.1.1"`.

Comment: For Angular 9, you need to use version 4.x. Check the documentation here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

Comment: @AshishDeora I installed v4.0.1 and it worked. If you write the above comment as answer I can accept it.

Comment: Done. I have added my answer. Thank you for the courtesy 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Angular 9, you need to use version 4.x. Check the documentation [here](http://npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select) -

Answer (score 1):

You missed to import **ngModule** in your app.module.ts, so it doesn't uderstand the *@NgModule({* decoration.
Missed the **import { AppComponent } from './app.component';**  as well.

```
// app.module.ts
...
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
```

Comment: Still I'm getting the error. I have edited the question

Comment: Do you missed the line **import { AppComponent } from './app.component';**  as well?

Comment: Sorry code was huge. So I missed it while simplifying. Already it's being imported in the actual code

Comment: In order to get a better help, It should be better if you could reproduce your simplified code causing the same error in a stackblizt sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't import **NgModule** & **AppComponent**.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
```

Comment: Sorry I'm already importing the ngModule. Missed it while editing the code here.

Comment: Still, getting the error?

Comment: Yes, Still error is there.

Comment: Is it the same error or different?

Comment: Same error. ngModule import was already there.

Comment: try this, providers: [APP_INITIALIZER] ---->
add APP_INITIALIZER into providers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240447/discussion-between-vinay-somawat-and-shyam3089).